# Spring Boot Security throws 401 Authentication error on API calls even if credentials are true

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, glassfish

I'm developing a single page application with Spring Boot & React using JWT Authentication. I've used the Embedded Tomcat from spring-boot-starter-tomcat during development and configured & tested every handler/method of my API successfully.

## Edit: I had a change of heart about my choice of app.server and use Wildfly instead. See my *answer* for details.

Then I packaged and deployed the app as a WAR to an application server/servlet container etc. application started to deny authenticated() requests from both my client and the rest client 'RESTClient' on firefox. I've monitored the request through my JwtFilter and it wasn't the wrong credentials.

I have tried consuming the rest endpoints from Glassfish 4.1.2 (build 1) with no luck. Also due to some mysterious reason server.log for glassfish is flooded by [Thread - 8] unknown.jul.logger -- Timestamp ... same ... output so no server output concerning request denial for the moment,
I also deployed the app on Apache Tomcat 8.5.23  and the error message when requesting secured resource is as below :

```
JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint      : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

My app supposed to secure all requests except those under /api/auth/** and it was perfectly doing so whe running on embedded tomcat in IntelliJ Debug mode.
My former call to the server from both client code (using axios) and RESTClient was as below :

```
(GET) http://localhost:8080/api/user/me
```

on app.server/web container :

```
(GET) http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/user/me
```

**The problem is, the secure rest endpoints were accepting authenticated requests on embedded tomcat on IntelliJ Debug mode, after WAR deployment it mysteriously rejecting all secure requests.**

I followed the steps [from spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) on using maven for WAR packaging, [GitHub page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/f47d60e7d47f9c91fc453c9c40248ef1d36acaad/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-deployment-tests) on spring boot deployment tests for glassfish, tomcat, wildfly etc.. and ended up with a project whose base classes are as following :

**Main class, (with @SpringBootApplication)**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        AccountingApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class
})
public class AccountingApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<AccountingApplication> applicationClass = AccountingApplication.class;
}
```

Below is my **security config**,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder.
            userDetailsService(userDetailsService).
            passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}

@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    /* removed for clarity */
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.woff",
                        "/**/*.woff2",
                        "/**/*.ttf",
                        "/**/*.eot",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myproject-web</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.my.MainApplication</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Exclusion of artifacts as instructed in Spring Boot deployment docs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provided scope because of the dependency collision during WAR deployment -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To access DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>myproject</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG
# App properties
app.jwtSecret= jwtSecretKey
app.jwtExpirationInMs = 604800000
```

**one misbehaving controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public UserProfile getCurrentUser(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser) {
        UserProfile userSummary = new UserProfile(currentUser.getId(), currentUser.getUsername(), currentUser.getName());
        return userSummary;
    }
}
```

Lastly, I present the filter configuration during container booting if anyone wonder if any custom filtering interferes with the expected flow.

```
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
.s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
```

Spring Boot ver. 2.0.1-RELEASE
Build mgmt. tool : Maven

Sorry for the long post, anything I can provide just ask in the comments.

Comment: There has been an update on this topic, When I deploy the war to standalone Tomcat *in debug mode* it acted up a little bit but when I tested the access/security issue I talked about above was gone. Then in the production mode I successfully requested secure resources from server.

Comment: About glassfish, I opted out for not deploying to glassfish after a couple of sleepless nights and discovering that it's going to take more than just tweaking some .xml files instead it'll require more fine tuning on servlet level which I am not that comfortable messing with. But I am sure this is an issue of glassfish being an application server and having all that modules, *provided* .jars etc. conflicting with my project dependencies and all. I wish the best of luck to anyone who is about to take on with it.

Comment: I do have same problem in deploying WAR on glassfish. It's working find with embedded tomcat server. how would you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

So, I explained the tomcat and glassfish issues on the comments of the question, I'd like to share the details about Wildfly deployment.

I used the Wildfly version 10.1.Final for deployment, tested also with 11.0.Final and don't think that it'd cause any trouble deploying to 12.0.Final.

To be able to deploy you need the above SpringBootServletInitializer extension for the main class and you need to have the following structure in your POM.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provided scope because of the dependency collision during WAR deployment -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

By default, wildfly 10.1.Final uses Hibernate Validator 5.x.Final with Bean Validation 1.1 and `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency *at the time of this writing* provides Hibernate Validator 6.0.5.Final with Bean Validation 2.0.

So in order to deploy and not crash in the middle of a server call due to some validation error you need to make hibernate-validator `<scope>provided</scope>` and make sure you have org.hibernate.validator ^6.0.5 and javax.validation ^2.0 .jar among your app. server modules.

If anybody wishes to share their wisdom about the *unsolved problem* they're more than welcome.